# Python While Loop Issue

Tags: python, django

I'm blanking here. I want to grab all the users from the userbase, but then only loop through 10 of them (I'm leaving out code that would explain why I wouldn't just grab 10 users from the db in the first place).

```
users = User.objects.all()
i = 0
while i < 10:
    for user in users:
        if user.is_active:
            # do something
            i += 1
```

This is creating an endless loop... What stupid detail am I missing?

Comment: user.is_active condition is not true for 10 or more times. You need i += 1 under while i<10:. Right now, its under if user.is_active:

Comment: Do you have more than 10 active users in db?

Comment: Please note also you are iterating and _doing something_ on **all active users** anyway since actions are in a `for user in users` loop (i.e. **all**) while `i` check is out that loop...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to look for 10 *active* users, you're going to need to be a bit more clever.

```
for user in itertools.islice((x for x in users if x.is_active), 10):
  # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's not endless, it just runs through all users 10 times.

If you want the first 10 users (regardless if they're active or not):

```
while i < 10:
    user = users[i]
    if user.is_active:
        # do something
    i += 1
```

If you want the first 10 active users:

```
for user in users:
    if user.is_active:
        #do something
        i += 1
    if i >= 10:
        break
```

Comment: Your first statement is wrong, and your code sample will not work. It will create an endless loop if one of `users[:10]` is inactive.

Comment: Are you sure that this would work as expected? I mean that i increasing only when user active, but if there active and inactive users are mixed what then?

Answer (score 1):

The while-loops condition is not evaluated until you've passed through all the users. You could remove the while and put an `if i >= 10: break` at the end of the for loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow your code on paper and see what it does. You'll notice that you're not grabbing the first ten users, but you are iterating over all the users ten times. The for-loop iterates over all `user` in `users`, and the while-loop repeats the for-loop ten times.

Comment: This would only be true if only one user was active.

Comment: @Tim I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: If ten users are active, then `i` is `10` at the end of the `for` loop, so the `while` condition becomes `False` after just one run through the `while` loop.

Comment: If there are 2 active users then the loop will execute 5 times. 3 users 4 times, etc.

Comment: @Tim & @Ignacio: Oh, I didn't notice the `i += 1`. :|

Answer (score 0):

Mabybe your `i` is never reaching 10. Maybe not even 10 of your users active.

Maybe `i > 10` and the condition wasn't checked before that happens.

```
filter(lambda u:u.is_active, users)[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code would be equivalent to

```
users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)[:10]
for user in users:
    #do something
```

providing you have ten users.

Answer (score 0):

Except for using special iterators (sometimes you import tens of lines of code to write your in a single one, you can call it being clever ^^, while you could do the same with 5 lines and no imports) I think this is the typical case to use `break` in a `for` loop

```
users = User.objects.all()
i = 0
for user in users:
    if user.is_active:
        #do something
        i += 1
    if i == 10:
        break
else:
    #do something if less than 10 active users (if necessary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
[user for user in User.objects.all() if user.is_active][:10]
```

And in case you need to perform any action on such users you can use again list comprehension:

```
[action(usr) for usr in [user for user in User.objects.all() if user.is_active][:10]]
```

Or map:

```
map(action, [user for user in User.objects.all() if user.is_active][:10])
```